Bootloader won't load kernel into RAM
I am currently trying to make a very simple 16-bit x86 OS, however, my bootloader won't load the kernel into RAM. I already found the line in which the error seems to happen, but I don't know how to fix it.
Bootloader:
; boot.asm

BITS 16
ORG 0x7C00

%define ENDL 0x0D, 0x0A

entry:
    jmp main

main:
    mov si, msg_booting
    call prints

    mov si, dbug0
    call prints

    jmp load_kernel

prints:
    lodsb

    cmp al, 0
    je return

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07

    int 0x10
    jmp prints
 
load_kernel:
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov bx, 0x1000
    mov cx, 0x0001
    mov dx, 0x00
    mov ah, 0x02
    int 0x13        ; error appears to be here
    jc read_kernel_error

    jmp 0x1000

read_kernel_error:
    mov si, dbug1
    call prints

    jmp done

return:
    ret

done:
    hlt

msg_booting db "Booting...", ENDL, 0
dbug0 db "Jumping to 'load_kernel'...", ENDL, 0
dbug1 db "Kernel could not be loaded correctly", ENDL, 0

times 510 - ($ - $$) db 0
dw 0xAA55


Kernel:
; kernel.asm

BITS 16
ORG 0x1000

main:
    mov si, msg_hw
    call prints
    jmp done

prints:
    lodsb

    cmp al, 0
    je return

    mov ah, 0x0E
    mov bh, 0x00
    mov bl, 0x07

    int 0x10
    jmp prints

return:
    ret

done:
    hlt

msg_hw db "Hello World", 0x0D, 0x0A, 0


I then use NASM to compile bootloader and kernel into binary files:
nasm -f bin -o boot.bin boot.asm
and nasm -f bin -o kernel.bin kernel.asm
After that, I generate an empty floppy image and put the bootloader and kernel onto it:
dd if=/dev/zero of=floppy.img bs=512 count=2880
dd if=boot.bin of=floppy.img bs=512 count=1 conv=notrunc
dd if=kernel.bin of=floppy.img bs=512 seek=1 conv=notrunc
Next, I use QEMU to run my OS:
qemu-system-i386 -drive format=raw,file=floppy.img
The bootloader seems to work correctly, except for the part where it loads the kernel into the RAM. It jumps to read_kernel_error and tells me that it didn't load the kernel.
When everything works correctly, the bootloader should load the kernel into the RAM, as I already said. As you can tell, it doesn't though.
I have already tried tweaking the values in the first few lines of load_kernel in my bootloader:
load_kernel:
    mov ax, 0x0000
    mov bx, 0x1000
    mov cx, 0x0001
    mov dx, 0x00
    mov ah, 0x02

However, this also did not solve the problem.
I tried to keep the kernel as simple as possible (at least for now), the only thing it does is print a "Hello World" line.

Forgot to initialise es and your mov ax, 0000h before int 13h will leave al as zero. That register should specify how many sectors to load, so it is invalid to pass zero. Didn't study everything else in detail but those two are certainly wrong.

Thank you for the suggestions, it didn't completely fix it, but I wrote everything again with slight changes and now it works. Thanks again!

Seeing that "now it works." turned this question into something very unsatisfying for me and future readers. I suggest you either delete the question or better post an answer yourself with all of those 'slight changes' that made it work. It might earn you a couple of upvotes if you care to explain why the changes work.
